# ajax control toolkit exception

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web

i am using ajax control toolkit calender extender and i am getting the following exception:
**Call stack location:**
AjaxConrolTollkit.DLL!AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderControlBase.Dispose()
**Source File Information*

```
Locating source for 'f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {ee 1a 1d c3 d5 ca a 7d 84 6b 74 7f 51 e8 63 6b}
The file 'f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'f:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\80acd78aa4c25314\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ExtenderControlBase.cs'.
```

help me in this scenario . thanks in advance

Comment: You need to register your Ajax Control Toolkit in your `Web.config` file or at the top of your `aspx` page.

Comment: Like adaam said,register like this in aspx page.
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>

Comment: i have registered it :
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" %>

Comment: but even i have registered it it is still not working

Answer (score 1):

Drag and Drop the Tool script manager also when you drag and drop any control from ajax tool kit

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in Web.config file:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler"
       verb="*"
       path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
       type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</handlers>
```

This solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Use "ToolkitScriptManager" instead of "ScriptManager".

Comment: Can you flesh out this answer with some example code?